# fs2 stream to zip-compressed fs2stream

Tags: fs2, cats-effect

I have a stream of fs2 streams and I'd like to create a compressed stream ready to be written into file with `*.zip` extension or for downloading.

The problem is that stream never terminates. Here is the code:

```
package backup

import java.io.OutputStream

import cats.effect._
import cats.effect.implicits._
import cats.implicits._
import fs2.{Chunk, Pipe, Stream, io}
import java.util.zip.{ZipEntry, ZipOutputStream}
import fs2.concurrent.Queue

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, SyncVar}

// https://github.com/slamdata/fs2-gzip/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/fs2/gzip/package.scala
// https://github.com/scalavision/fs2-helper/blob/master/src/main/scala/fs2helper/zip.scala
// https://github.com/eikek/sharry/blob/2f1dbfeae3c73bf2623f65c3591d0b3e0691d4e5/modules/common/src/main/scala/sharry/common/zip.scala

object Fs2Zip {

  private def writeEntry[F[_]](zos: ZipOutputStream)(implicit F: Concurrent[F],
                                                     blockingEc: ExecutionContext,
                                                     contextShift: ContextShift[F]): Pipe[F, (String, Stream[F, Byte]), Unit] =
    _.flatMap {
      case (name, data) =>
        val createEntry = Stream.eval(F.delay {
          zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name))
        })
        val writeEntry = data.through(io.writeOutputStream(F.delay(zos.asInstanceOf[OutputStream]), blockingEc, closeAfterUse = false))
        val closeEntry = Stream.eval(F.delay(zos.closeEntry()))
        createEntry ++ writeEntry ++ closeEntry
    }

  private def zipP1[F[_]](implicit F: ConcurrentEffect[F],
                          blockingEc: ExecutionContext,
                          contextShift: ContextShift[F]): Pipe[F, (String, Stream[F, Byte]), Byte] = entries => {

    Stream.eval(Queue.unbounded[F, Option[Chunk[Byte]]]).flatMap { q =>
      Stream.suspend {
        val os = new java.io.OutputStream {

          private def enqueueChunkSync(a: Option[Chunk[Byte]]) = {
            println(s"enqueueChunkSync $a")
            val done = new SyncVar[Either[Throwable, Unit]]
            q.enqueue1(a).start.flatMap(_.join).runAsync(e => IO(done.put(e))).unsafeRunSync
            done.get.fold(throw _, identity)
            println(s"enqueueChunkSync done $a")
          }
          @scala.annotation.tailrec
          private def addChunk(c: Chunk[Byte]): Unit = {
            val free = 1024 - bufferedChunk.size
            if (c.size > free) {
              enqueueChunkSync(Some(Chunk.vector(bufferedChunk.toVector ++ c.take(free).toVector)))
              bufferedChunk = Chunk.empty
              addChunk(c.drop(free))
            } else {
              bufferedChunk = Chunk.vector(bufferedChunk.toVector ++ c.toVector)
            }
          }

          private var bufferedChunk: Chunk[Byte] = Chunk.empty

          override def close(): Unit = {
            // flush remaining chunk
            enqueueChunkSync(Some(bufferedChunk))
            bufferedChunk = Chunk.empty
            // terminate the queue
            enqueueChunkSync(None)
          }
          override def write(bytes: Array[Byte]): Unit =
            Chunk.bytes(bytes)
          override def write(bytes: Array[Byte], off: Int, len: Int): Unit =
            addChunk(Chunk.bytes(bytes, off, len))
          override def write(b: Int): Unit =
            addChunk(Chunk.singleton(b.toByte))
        }

        val write: Stream[F, Unit] = Stream
          .bracket(F.delay(new ZipOutputStream(os)))((zos: ZipOutputStream) => F.delay(zos.close()))
          .flatMap((zos: ZipOutputStream) => entries.through(writeEntry(zos)))

        val read = q.dequeue
          .unNoneTerminate
          .flatMap(Stream.chunk(_))

        read.concurrently(write)
      }
    }
  }

  def zip[F[_]: ConcurrentEffect: ContextShift](entries: Stream[F, (String, Stream[F, Byte])])(
      implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Stream[F, Byte] =
    entries.through(zipP1)
}
```

The code is shamelessly copied from https://github.com/eikek/sharry/blob/master/modules/common/src/main/scala/sharry/common/zip.scala
and updated to compile with the latest `fs2` and `cats-effect`

I narrowed the problem to `enqueueChunkSync`:

```
  private def enqueueChunkSync(a: Option[Chunk[Byte]]) = {
    val done = new SyncVar[Either[Throwable, Unit]]
    q.enqueue1(a).start.flatMap(_.join).runAsync(e => IO(done.put(e))).unsafeRunSync
    done.get.fold(throw _, identity)
  }
```

which blocks on the last chunk. When I put a `println` in there and make the buffer smaller I see that chunks are flushed successfully until the last one.
When I remove the blocking bit `done.get.fold(throw _, identity)` it seems to work, but then I imagine the bytes are flushed to the stream all at once?
How is the last chunk different from the previous ones?

Comment: Did you find a solution?